# Error passing argument to form in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am new with django and I try update some data passing the id_provider from form1 to form2
The form2 have to display the data of the provider

I have an html page with a little form(form1):

Is a a simple input text where the user write a number. 
the number is passed to other form as an argument.

My forms.py:

```
class ConfigForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,idprov,*args,**kwargs):
        super(ConfigForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.id_provider = idprov

    class Meta:
        model = Config
```

And my views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def configView(request):
    prov = get_object_or_404(Config, id_proveedor=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ConfigForm(request.post, instance=prov)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/monitor/')
    else:
       form = ConfigForm(Config.id_proveedor,instance=prov)
    return render_to_response('config.html',{'form':form},RequestContext(request))
```

This is the form(form2) where I try to display the data:

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<form method='POST' action='' class='form'>
   <div class="form-group">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
   </div>
        <button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary">Grabar</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I receive the error:

**TypeError at /config/**

**id() takes exactly one argument (0 given)**

I don't know if my error are in the method of the form where I try to update the data (form2) or I have some error in the view of the form.
I think I am not getting the value of the input text int the right way.

Any advice, link or snippet will be very helpful

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not passing `id` to the view and at the same time shadowing built-in [`id` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` is a Python function and you didn't create it

```
>>> id('test')
35092128
```

Try

```
@csrf_exempt
def configView(request):
    # Get your ID in another way for example this one
    pk = request.POST.get('id', None)
    if pk is None:
        # Handle error

    prov = get_object_or_404(Config, id_proveedor=pk)
    #                                             ^^
```

should works

BTW using `csrf_exempt` is generally not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks Regis only one thing when the user click the save button a message Page Not FOUN 404 is displayed I try to redirect to the index page,but always this error are displayed. But Thanks the form retrieve the data I want

Comment: With the code you gave, there's only two possibilites : First your form action is not defined, second, `get_object_or_404` will raise a Http404 error if pk is not found. You know : `print` should a very close friend of you ;)